# how to count down from server and triguring event after time

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am making an website where i will arrange contest.If moderator initiate a test then count down will start . After finishing the countdown, an event "Exam" will start ,and after the finishing time automatically page will be refreshed and result will be shown , It's similar to online judges .Would u any one plz help? Advance thanks.

Comment: Hi shohed shakil and welcome to SO. You haven't asked a question or showed that you tried something and/or did some research on this. Please do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the starttime and endtime of an exam in a database. Everytime a user opens the webpage you send the starttime and endtime in the html code and let a javascript do the 'timing'.
So a script check if an exam has started (and if it hasn't it shows a countdown). And when the endtime is reached it will refresh the page (and posting the data the user has entered).

If you have that working you should think about some securety.. since javascript runs on the usermachine it can be changed... But I think you can figure out some clever handshake kind of structure that takes care of validating the data...